# Using Qt for OAuth 2.0 Server to Server authenication, token request returns invalid_grant intermittently

Tags: qt, openssl, google-cloud-storage

I hate intermittent problems so hopefully someone can help me figure out what could be causing my problem. I have been battling with accessing Google cloud storage using Openssl and Qt. I have had some success. The problem is that I receive an invalid_grant more often than I receive a valid token. My assumption is that there is something up with the time data I am supplying to my claim set. It can take a few requests before I get an access token back.

How does this look for calculating the iat and exp paramters of the claim set?

```
QDateTime now = QDateTime::currentDateTime();
QDateTime utcNow = now.toUTC();
qint32 secs = utcNow.toTime_t();
```

where iat = secs and exp = secs+3600.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok got it. The intermittence is coming from not percentEncoding the assertion when I add it to my postdata. Before I made this change I would receive the token when the QBytearray, that represented the encoded signature, did not contain any '+' symbols.

So now I am receiving the token consistently.

Answer (score 0):

Google's OAuth 2 server restricts you to requesting only a certain number of refresh tokens and access tokens. If you're running the app very frequently, it's entirely possible that you are being rate limited. Make sure to cache refresh and access tokens for as long as possible.

Also, I believe toUTC() is superfluous in your example. `toTime_t()` always returns the number of seconds since the UTC epoch.

Comment: Ok, I've droppped the toUTC and obviously I am getting the same behaviour.

I don't think what I am experiencing has anything to do with rate limiting since the very first call to the cloud service will return an invalid_grant, if I fire off a few more requests I will will probably get a token after half a dozen tries.